# Jquery fadeTo, fadeIn keeps repearting itself

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm new to making animation and i have several div's that contains an img in css
so

```
.div1 {
background: url(path to the img);
}
```

At the moment I'm trying to make is disappear when I hover and when the cursor isn't hovering it should re-appear

this is my jquery

```
$("#text_container").hide();

$(".hide_container").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(5000,0);
    $("#text_container").fadeIn(5000);
});

$(".hide_container").mouseleave (function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(5000,1);
    $("#text_container").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

The HTML

```
 <div class="hide_container">             
               <div id="eyes_container">
                    <div id="left_container">
                       <div class="left_eyebrow"></div>
                       <div class="eye_left"></div>
                    </div> 

                    <div id="right_container">
                       <div class="right_eyebrow"></div>
                       <div class="eye_right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="top_eyes_container">
                     <div class="top_eyes"></div>
                </div>



                <div id="arms_container">
                    <div class="left_arm">
                        <div class="h">
                            Hover
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="right_arm">
                        <div class="os">
                            Over Steve
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img class="steve_jobs" src="images/steve_jobs.png" width="557" alt="">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="glasses_container">
                    <div class="glasses"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="text_container">
                    <div class="g_a"></div>
                    <div class="gle_a"></div> 
                </div>
```

i tried the .stop() but since i don't know where I have to put it, it was probably in the wrong element.

the problem I have is that when i hover it disappears but then when the mouse stays in place it re-appears and keeps repeating itself

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Greeting
Ditger

Comment: Could you add your HTML to the question, as it may be possible to do this in CSS alone which would be a far better solution than using JS

Comment: html has been added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this only with css. see snippet below

first you set `opacity:0` to `#text_container` to hide it from view, then at hover you make `.hide_container` invisible with `opacity:0` and using general siblings connector `~` you connect `.hide_container:hover` with `#text_container` ( they are on the same level in HTML therefore siblings )

```css
#text_container {
 opacity:0;
}
.hide_container:hover {
 opacity:0;
}
.hide_container:hover ~ #text_container {
 opacity:1;
}
#text_container,.hide_container {
 transition:5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide_container">
  <div id="eyes_container">
    <div id="left_container">
      <div class="left_eyebrow"></div>
      <div class="eye_left"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right_container">
      <div class="right_eyebrow"></div>
      <div class="eye_right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="top_eyes_container">
    <div class="top_eyes"></div>
  </div>



  <div id="arms_container">
    <div class="left_arm">
      <div class="h">
        Hover
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_arm">
      <div class="os">
        Over Steve
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="glasses_container">
  <div class="glasses"></div>
</div>

<div id="text_container">
  <div class="g_a">a</div>
  <div class="gle_a">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the only thing i need to do is let the images within the text container reappear, but reeally thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: they re-appear . just move mouse cursor outside the snippet . ( the .hide_container with is 100% so it occupies the whole width of the snippet )  for example, after hovering, move mouse cursor here on the comments

Comment: oh god, i made is set on display none in my jquery :D

I keep learning ;)